# How to update LaTeX using tlmgr?

Tags: mac, update, tlmgr

I'm having a lot of trouble updating LaTeX on my Mac. I have never done this, but I do have the 2016 version of LaTeX, so I think I only need to update the packages. I read that the tlmgr package using "tlmgr update --all" would be the update I need. However, LaTeX keeps asking me for a file.

What I wrote is LaTeX is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tlmgr}


\begin{document}

tlmgr update --all

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: tlmgr is a _command_ not a latex package, you need to type the command on the commandline (terminal) not put it in a latex file. But I thought theat mactex had some kind of gui front end

Comment: If you have the application "TeX Live Utility.app", you can use this to update

Comment: the premise of this question is oddly amusing

Comment: What is the thing you are trying to compile?

Answer (score 7):

`tlmgr` is not a tex package — it’s a program, distributed with TeXLive.  So to run it, you don’t load it in a TeX document.  Instead, open the Terminal (on Mac OS, go to the Applications folder, and then inside that the Utilities folder, and the Terminal should be in there); and then in the Terminal’s window, type the `tlmgr` command you want, e.g.

> `tlmgr update --all`

and then hit Enter/Return to tell the Terminal to run the command.

Comment: On Mac you need to run tlmgr using sudo as latex is owned by root. It also a good idea to use the `--self` option, then tlmgr will also be updated if there are any updates for it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the MacOS version: `TeX Live Utility`, a graphical interface which can be put in the dock.