# How do I transition from natbib to biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, biber, spanish

I am new to LaTeX and I've been reading that apparently the `biblatex` package would suit me better than `natbib`. I read [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) but I can't make it work with my document.

This is a sample of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle, spanish=mexican]{csquotes}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} %Bibliografía
\bibliographystyle{humannat} % 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\NAT@open{\color{blue}(}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the text of the document which includes \cite{examples} and \citep{examples} from a 
.bib document saved in the same folder of the .tex document.
\bibliography{Bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

I simple do not know what to do and I am not sure if I can't use my `.bib` file named Bibliografia or if i need to use something for `biber`. I tried adding the options `natbib=true`, the commands `\printbibliography` while erasing the commands for `natbib` `\bibliographystyle` `\bibliography{}`.

I just don't know what to do than sticking with my `natbib` options. Should I change the `inputenc`and `babel` package to suit spanish with `biblatex`or something? is there a problem with that `usc` package or `hyperref` can't be used with `biblatex`?

EDIT: [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427976/126835) answer has worked but now I have to fix hyperref and colour the citation part that I had fixed with the `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` commands. Any ideas?

Comment: You are not using the right commands. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) show at the end a minimal example of  how use biblatex (including natbib=true)  and explain the compilation process. Compare with the above examples not using biblatex. Check than you can compile the last example  *as is* with biber.

Answer (score 10):

[What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/) already lists the step you have to do (in no particular order)

- Replace `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` with `\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}`.
- Remove `\bibliographystyle{humannat}`.
- Remove `\bibliography{Bibliografia}` and add `\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}` (*with* file extension!) in the preamble (in theory you could keep using `\bibliography{Bibliografia}`, but it must be moved into the preamble, it can't stay after `\begin{document}`; `\addbibresource` is preferred over `\bibliography`).
- Add `\printbibliography` where you want to see your bibliography.
- Use `\textcite` instead of `\citet`, `\parencite` instead of `\citep`. Alternatively, you may keep on using `\citet` and `\citep` if you add `natbib=true` to the loading options.

You'll have to apply a few more tweaks as well

- Remove `\usepackage{ucs}` - it is incompatible with `biblatex`.
- Replace `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. For Spanish texts `utf8` should be enough.
- Remove the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` bit redefining `\NAT@open`. That works for `natbib` but not for `biblatex`.

Your document should look roughly like this now

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle, spanish=mexican]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue}

\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}

\begin{document}
This is the text of the document which includes \cite{examples} and \parencite{examples} from a 
.bib document saved in the same folder of the .tex document.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Finally and extremely importantly, configure your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX for you, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)
When with `natbib` you used to run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX you now need to run (assuming your document is called `paper.tex`)

```
pdflatex paper
biber paper
pdflatex paper
pdflatex paper
```

[Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) explains what Biber does really well, but you will want to look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) to get your editor to run Biber.

If you have problems with this at first, delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and recompile from scratch. [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) gives some handy first advice in case you have problems getting Biber to run.

There is nothing special you need to do to get the support for Spanish working, it should work out of the box because `biblatex` picks up the language from `babel`.

Comment: I did as you said but I'm getting two error messages now. The first is that the command \addbibliography{} is not recognized. It is undefined. The other is : ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.2.
This means that your biber (2.6) and biblatex (3.11) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.

Comment: For the first error, note the misspelling of `addbibliograhphy` in this answer. I'd use `addbibresource` there. For the second error I'd update using `tlmgr`, e.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367996/how-to-update-latex-using-tlmgr

Comment: I redid the whole document and updated the packages using MikTex update. It has worked now! But now I need to find a way to replace the \makeatletter - \makeatother part to hyperref and colour the whole citatio.

Comment: @Ramashalanka Thanks for catching that. Corrected now.

Comment: @Jebal The thing about the hyperref is a new question. But you can have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425283/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864